# Preventing caching of server side include files

Tags: caching, asp-classic, ssi

I have a classic ASP page that calls in some other ASP files using Server Side Includes.

I want neither the main file nor the included files to be cached by any browser.

At the moment my main looks something like this:

```
<%@ Language="VBSCRIPT" %><% Option Explicit %>
<%
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires=-1
%> 
<!--#include file="scripts1.asp"-->
<!--#include file="scripts2.asp"-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>myTitle</title>
<!--#include file="head.asp"-->
</head>
<body>
<!--#include file="body.asp"-->
</body>
</html>
```

I have only placed the Response.CacheControl, Response.AddHeader, Response.Expires code on the main page and not on the included files.

My questions are:

1. Do all server side included ASP pages need the `Response.CacheControl`,  `Response.AddHeader` and `Response.Expires` code that I have used, or just the main file?
2. Is the code I have used sufficient to prevent caching on all browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the "master" output page needs the headers, as you've shown. The server-side include happens internally on the server, so the browser never sees it.

You're doing it right.